# Installing RAM: `dmidecode` shows both DIMM and SODIMM slots on the same machine

Tags: ram, nixos, dmidecode

I want to add RAM to my laptop. If I run `dmidecode --type 17` (as described in [Linux Check Ram Speed and Type Commands](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/check-ram-speed-linux/)). I get the following:

```
[jeff@jbb-dell:~]$ sudo dmidecode --type 17
[sudo] password for jeff: 
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x003B, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x003A
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: Unknown
        Data Width: Unknown
        Size: No Module Installed
        Form Factor: DIMM             # huh?
        Set: None
        Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
        Bank Locator: BANK 0
        Type: Unknown
        Type Detail: None
        Speed: Unknown
        Manufacturer: Not Specified
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Rank: Unknown
        Configured Memory Speed: Unknown
        Minimum Voltage: Unknown
        Maximum Voltage: Unknown
        Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x003C, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x003A
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: SODIMM             # huh?
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM B
        Bank Locator: BANK 2
        Type: DDR4
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 2400 MT/s
        Manufacturer: SK Hynix
        Serial Number: 71DB323B
        Asset Tag: 01173300
        Part Number: HMA81GS6AFR8N-UH    
        Rank: 1
        Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
```

That output is divided into two sections, which I believe should correspond to two slots on my machine where RAM can go. The first is empty; the second contains an 8 GB chip. I thought I'd fill both slots with 8 GB chips.

But notice the two lines marked "huh?" For the empty slot, that "Form Factor" is indicated as DIMM. In the filled slot, it is SODIMM. (I am not alone -- the  article [How To Find Out Maximum Supported RAM In Linux](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-find-out-maximum-supported-ram-in-linux/), on OSTechNix.com, shows similar output, but doesn't flag it as a problem.)

I thought the two slots were always the same shape.

I use [this Dell Inspiron laptop from 2017](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0746LZK1R) running NixOS.

Comment: It seems the memory module itself says whether it's SO-DIMM or DIMM:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect   Maybe the memory controller is unable to tell what kind of slots are on the motherboard?